# How to run ruby code in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, ruby, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Jupyter with conda, and iruby according to instructions here https://github.com/SciRuby/iruby, and there are 2 ways to start jupyter:

1. `iruby notebook` (given in the README)
2. In VSCode with the Jupyter extensions

The first method using iruby seems to require ipython and gives the error `[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | File 'notebook' doesn't exist`

The second method seems better, but it is difficult to manage which gems and version are needed.

Is there best practice for using Jupyter with ruby? Is ipython required and supported?

Comment: You haven't mentioned your environment. Have you followed all the OS-specific instructions given in the `Iruby` readme?

Comment: Try looking at [Running ruby on Jupyter notebooks](https://dev.to/alec/running-ruby-on-jupiter-notebooks-2a2f).

Comment: @AliasCartellano Thank you.  It does run on my Mac using the `jupyter notebook` command from that link, rather than the 2 methods above that I tried.